# Counting self avoiding walks in a strip

Tags: co.combinatorics

Consider the strip $\{0,1,\ldots n\}\times\{0,1,2\}$ in $\mathbb{N}^2.$ Is a formula known for the total number of self avoiding walks in this strip starting at $(0,0)$ in terms of the parameter $n$?

*Edit:* I mean *all* the walks that take steps of $(\pm 1,0),(0,\pm1)$ as long as they are confined to that strip.

**Note:** Asked on math.stackexchange (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3537621/counting-self-avoiding-walks-in-a-strip)) a week ago with no specific answer.

Comment: Yes. Do you know the transfer-matrix method?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: The OP wants self-avoiding walks only.

Comment: I know. This is why the method has to be applied to a suitable graph. See Faase, "On the number of specific spanning subgraphs of $G \times P_n$". Here it is explained how to count self-avoiding paths from one point on the "left" to one point on the "right", but something similar works for general end-points, and then we just sum up.

Comment: A special case of this was Problem A2 of the 2005 Putnam exam.  It was in the context of a rook's tour on 3 by $n$ chessboard, counting paths from $(1,1)$ to $(n,1)$ that visited each square exactly once.  For the current problem, these are maximal SAWs with a specified endpoint.